# Php variable in javascript markup

Tags: php, javascript, variables

How do I exactly put a php value in a js line? I tried:

```
$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range:{min: "<?= $field[ 'range_min' ] ?>" , max: "<?= $field[ 'range_max' ] ?>" }});
```

First I had it the other way around, I echoed the javascript line in php and put the fields with:

`' . $field[ 'range_min' ] . '`

That worked fine but I think php in js would be a cleaner way to do this.
How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to `echo` right?

Answer (score 2):

To print variable in PHP you shoud do:

```
<?php echo $field[ 'range_min' ]; ?>
```

or

```
<?=$field[ 'range_min' ]; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range:{min: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_min' ]; ?>" , max: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_max' ]; ?>" }});
```

you need to echo it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `echo`.

```
$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range:{min: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_min' ] ?>" , max: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_max' ] ?>" }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons and you need to echo:

```
$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range:{min: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_min' ]; ?>" , max: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_max' ]; ?>" }});
```

Answer (score 0):

DO that:

```
$("#slider").editRangeSlider({range:{min: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_min' ]; ?>" , max: "<?php echo $field[ 'range_max' ]; ?>" }});
```

You have forgot to echoing it.